# Rounding BigDecimal to *always* have two decimal places

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal, rounding

I'm trying to round BigDecimal values up, to two decimal places.

I'm using

```
BigDecimal rounded = value.round(new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.CEILING));
logger.trace("rounded {} to {}", value, rounded);
```

but it doesn't do what I want consistently:

```
rounded 0.819 to 0.82
rounded 1.092 to 1.1
rounded 1.365 to 1.4 // should be 1.37
rounded 2.730 to 2.8 // should be 2.74
rounded 0.819 to 0.82
```

I don't care about significant digits, I just want two decimal places. How do I do this with BigDecimal? Or is there another class/library better suited to this?

Comment: If you actually want to round, you would use RoundingMode.HALF_UP

Answer (score 466, accepted):

```
value = value.setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING)
```

Comment: That does indeed work how I want. Is the difference simply that `round()` works with significant digits while `setScale` works with a fixed number of decimal places or is there more to it?

Comment: Use RoundingMode.HALF_UP to do "typcal rounding". That is 1.111 gives 1.11 [CEILING gives 1.12]

Comment: Thanks for `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`. As per documentation it is the rounding method commonly taught in schools - what I needed.

Comment: Take care if your values can be negative as in an accounting application. You may need to use RoundingMode.UP instead of CEILING

Comment: Why does `setScale(...)` work? see [BigDecimal setScale and round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843440/bigdecimal-setscale-and-round).

Comment: I want 1.00 divided by 3 BigDecimal to get 0.33. But then i am getting 0.30.