# Using Java BigDecimal for a 15 precision digit (scale of 2)

Tags: java, precision, bigdecimal

I found a partial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643280/rounding-bigdecimal-to-always-have-two-decimal-places), but I knew this already. So I decided to post a new question.

I am trying to convert a HTTP request parameter string to a 15 precision Java BigDecimal number (with scaling of 2). For example,

```
String x = request.getParameter("seqNo"); /* e.g. 12345678910111213141516.17181920 whatever */
// I want to convert x so that it has a precision of 15 and scale of 2 i.e. 111213141516.17.
```

I don't care about rounding. It's a form of reference number, so irrelevant of rounding. I know that scaling can be set by using overloaded `setScale(int)` method that will return a scaled(Truncated?) BigDecimal. But how to make sure that the precision is set properly?

Comment: So you want to not just round the trailing digits, but also ignore the *leading* digits? This doesn't sound like you should be treating it as a *number* at all, to be honest... can you tell us more about what the input is meant to represent?

Comment: @JonSkeet        as mentioned in the question, a reference number, for internal reference for the developers

Comment: "A reference number" is far from a detailed description. Why are the digits before the "111" in your example irrelevant? As per the answer from Anony-Mousse, this really shouldn't be thought of as a number, IMO.

Comment: What if they decide to add another component next week? Say they use multiple servers now, and next week their ids are `1234567.89012345.5` where the last component is the server number, and they really need this one... **treat it as string, and you are safe**, anything else will drive you crazy eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using substring instead? It's not really a number anyway.

```
int pos = x.indexOf('.');
String y = x.substring(pos - 12, pos + 3);
```

If you are really crazy enough to try processing this as numbers (collissions and differences in rounding are going to break your neck sooner or later!), you could do this.

```
double v = Double.parseDouble(y); // REALLY REALLY REALLY NOT RECOMMENDED.
```

But **this is a *very* *very* bad idea**. Don't squeeze something into a number column that is *not* a number. Next week, you'll get numbers with two dots, and it will break in every possible way.

If you do not need to do *mathematical computations*, treating such a field as `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` is perfectly acceptable. Because that is what it is: a sequence of characters. Not a number.

In fact, **I would strongly advise to store the whole number, as `VARCHAR`**. It is a *unique identifier*, not a mathematical number to do computations with.

Comment: well, i am trying to pesist it to SQL server and the recommended DECIMAL(p,s) type equivalent in java is BigDecimal. But yes, it seems like one of the ways.

Comment: Why don't you use `TEXT` or `VARCHAR`? Hacking this ID - which supposedly is not a number - into a numeric column type by truncation just sounds like the worst possible solution.

Comment: Fix the requirement, instead of breaking the data. It isn't the first time the requirements turn out to be flawed. And this sounds like the requirement is just BROKEN!

Comment: @ha9u63ar What kind of requirement is there that forces you to treat something that is not a decimal number as a decimal number?