# Trying to limit number of decimal places for BigDecimal division Java

Tags: java

I am new to the Java world and am trying to learn how to use BigDecimal. What I am trying to do now is limit the number of decimal places in a division problem. My line of code is:

```
quotient=one.divide(x);
```

Where quotient, one and x are all of type BigDecimal. I cannot figure out, however, how to limit the number of decimal places to print out, saying that x is some large number, and one is equal to 1. All help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Use a number formatter for outputting the `BigDecimal` as you want.

Comment: You might wanna give this a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395825/how-to-print-formatted-bigdecimal-values

Comment: Try and use the `.setScale()` method; read the javadoc carefully, though

Answer (score 1):

That code will die a horrible death if the division has a non-terminating decimal expansion. See javadoc of [`divide(BigDecimal divisor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal%29):

> if the exact quotient cannot be represented (because it has a non-terminating decimal expansion) an `ArithmeticException` is thrown.

Example:

```java
BigDecimal one = BigDecimal.ONE;
BigDecimal x = BigDecimal.valueOf(7);
one.divide(x); // throws java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.
```

Use one of the other overloads of `divide()`, e.g. [`divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, RoundingMode roundingMode)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal,%20int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29):

```java
BigDecimal one = BigDecimal.ONE;
BigDecimal x = BigDecimal.valueOf(7);
BigDecimal quotient = one.divide(x, 5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(quotient); // prints: 0.14286
```

```java
BigDecimal one = BigDecimal.ONE;
BigDecimal x = BigDecimal.valueOf(7);
BigDecimal quotient = one.divide(x, 30, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(quotient); // prints: 0.142857142857142857142857142857
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the number of decimal places in a variable BigDecimal you can use the following sentences depend that you want achieve

`value = value.setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING)` to do 'cut' the part after 2 decimals

or

`value = value.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)` to do common round

See [Rounding BigDecimal to *always* have two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15643280/2403791)