# How to scale a BigDecimal in Java?

Tags: java

```
import java.math.*;

class Moqueet {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        double a, b, c;
        BigDecimal bg1, bg2;
        a = 1;
        b = 10000;
        c = a / b;
        bg1 = new BigDecimal(c);
        MathContext mc = new MathContext(10);
        bg2 = bg1.round(mc);
        System.out.println(bg1);
    }
    }
```

when I try this I get output as follow:

```
0.000100000000000000004792173602385929598312941379845142364501953125
```

I want my out put as `0.0001` only. How can I achive this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643280/rounding-bigdecimal-to-always-have-two-decimal-places

Comment: Note that "scaling" and "rounding" are two different things. You just want rounding here. Also note that you're printing `bg1` and ignoring `bg2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 bg1 = bg1.setScale(4, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
```