# How do you allow a double with multiple decimals to only show, NOT ROUND, one decimal

Tags: java

How do you change a double to only show one decimal? 
I'm not trying to round it but to only display one decimal of a number.

For example, for 6.7542, I want it to display to 6.7 not 6.8.

Thanks.

Comment: Use BigDecimal setScale..

> [BigDecimal setScale and round][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843440/bigdecimal-setscale-and-round

Comment: Next time try putting more than 0 effort into your research.