# BigDecimal divide with a large number of decimal places

Tags: java, bigdecimal

My question is very simple

In `BigDecimal` I want to do this:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(1).divide(new BigDecimal(3));
}
```

I want the result to be this : `0.333333333333333333333333333333333.......`
and not `0.3334` or `0.33`.

Comment: You know there are an _infinite_ amount of 3's there? What is the precision you are looking for?

Comment: yeah , and i went the big number i can get

Comment: As big as what? As the memory allows you? Why do you want to store 1/3 to billions of billions of decimal?

Comment: Just append `...`, that's the biggest you can get :)

Comment: The only way to represent this number exactly is with a fraction. If you use `double` or `BigDecimal` you can only approximate it.

Comment: so i will scale it maybe by 100 ?

Comment: @zebiridjallil you can if you like but it is still an approximation. If you scale it to 15 digits and use rounding, you could just use a `double` and make your code much simpler `(1.0/3)`

Comment: How many decimal places do you need? Just set the precision accordingly.

Comment: Maybe use rather [Fraction](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/fraction.html) instead of BigDecimal?

Comment: @Henry implies that you can specify the decimal places to anything you want. This is incorrect.  For example, scale = 4680 does not work.  4679 does. Don't ask why the limit is set to that; Looking at the source code of BigDecimal, I suspect that it is intrinsically set (does not seem to be extrinsic).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All BigDecimal operations allow to set precision (number of digits after decimal point) and rounding mode.

```
System.out.println(
    new BigDecimal(1).divide(new BigDecimal(3), 10, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
```

will output `0.3333333333`. You can create a MathContext object to encapsulate this information. This is helpful since you typically need to do several operations with the same precision and rounding settings.

```
MathContext mc = new MathContext(10, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(1).divide(new BigDecimal(3), mc));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(1).divide(new BigDecimal(9), mc));
```

Comment: I believe the "10" in `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(1).divide(new BigDecimal(3), 10, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));` means scale, which is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point. and the "10" in MathContext means precision, which is the number of significant digits. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843440 Try to divide 20 by 3 and you will see the difference.