# BigDecimal and MathContext

Tags: java

Can someone explain why those two have different results?

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(1234.5678)
    .divide(
        new BigDecimal(1.19),
        4,
        RoundingMode.CEILING
    );
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(1234.5678)
    .divide(
        new BigDecimal(1.19),
        new MathContext(4, RoundingMode.CEILING)
    );
```

**Result**:

```
bd1: 1037.4520
bd2: 1038
```

Comment: I take it the MCVE I put together for you demonstrates the problem?

Comment: You made the example worse. Don't use double literals for BigDecimal constructors if you can avoid it. Floating point precision makes the example **less** clear. `1234.5678` will not be `1234.5678`.

Comment: @Michael That is the point. My real example is something similar. I have something like 2074523.35687 as input

Comment: Use a string then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in `MathContext(4, RoundingMode.CEILING)`, 4 is precision, but in `.divide(new BigDecimal(1.19), 4, RoundingMode.CEILING);`, 4 is scale. You can see difference between "precision" and "scale" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843440/bigdecimal-setscale-and-round)

> One important point that is alluded to but not directly addressed is
>   the difference between "**precision**" and "**scale**" and how they are used
>   in the two statements. "**precision**" is the total number of significant
>   digits in a number. "**scale**" is the number of digits to the right of
>   the decimal point.

So if you change second one to

```
final BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(1234.5678)
        .divide(
                new BigDecimal(1.19),
                new MathContext(8, RoundingMode.CEILING)
        );
```

You have same results:

```
1037.4520
1037.4520
```